# DerivedData Materials

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I am having a problem in running one of my projects.It says

> "Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Material/io.cosmicmind.material.fonts.bundle:
>   No such file or directory"

I checked the location. It cant find it because it creates it's file inside

> Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Material/Material/.io.cosmicmind.material.fonts.bundle

Any solution about this? Im using the latest xcode and latest release of Material.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in 1.39.5.

Also, please clear you DerivedData folder and clean your build folder, as suggested by @pavan

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply open the preferences of Xcode and go to locations tab, on there click on the arrow given in derived data section or either copy path and go into finder.

press cmd + shift + g and paste on there

Clear all things on this path. now come back to project in xcode and open the product menu with pressing alt key.

now select "clean build folder". and build again and run app.

its works fine.